# Azure Function Read local.settings.json to object

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-functions

I know i could add all my environment vars under the values {} section of local.settings.json. I am however trying to keep a tidy home and would like if I could do something like this.

local.settings.json

```
   {
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
"Hello": "world"
 },
"ClientConfiguration": {
    "this": "that",
    "SubscriberEndpoint": "",
    "Username": "",
    "Password": "",
    "ObjectEndpoint": ""
 }
}
```

in my code i have

```
 var config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myConnectionObject> (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientConfiguration"));
```

No matter what I do I cannot get this to work. Why can't I at least get the contents of ClientConfiguration? Just keeps coming back null.

IF I add ClientConfiguration {} to the values like

```
..."Values" : { ... 
"Hello":"world",
"ClientCOnfiguration" : {above}
}
```

I end up with an error saying azurewebjobsstorage can't be found and 'func settings list' is just empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `local.settings.json`, only `Values` section can be imported into Environment variables.(If your function is v2, `ConnectionStrings` section is also there in Environment variables). So you see null as the result.

What's more, `Values` section is a `Dictionary<string, string>` which means value can't be in other format except string. Hence your `ClientCOnfiguration` inside results in error .

Since you want to reorganize those settings, serializing `ClientConfiguraiton` to store it in `Values` seems not a good option. We may need simply reading and parsing Json file.

Add `ExecutionContext context` in your function method signature and try code below.

```
var reader = new StreamReader(context.FunctionAppDirectory+"/local.settings.json");
var myJson = reader.ReadToEnd();
dynamic config =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJson);
var clientConfiguration = config.ClientConfiguration as JObject;
myConnectionObject mco = clientConfiguration.ToObject<myConnectionObject>();
```

If your function is v2, there's another way with `ConfigurationBuilder`.

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
var mco = new myConnectionObject();
config.GetSection("ClientConfiguration").Bind(mco);
```

Note that `local.settings.json` is for local dev, it won't be uploaded to Azure by default. Need to remove `<CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>` in `functionname.csproj`.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I was hoping to avoid all that, especially readinging the settings.json from a reader since it won't work in azure correctly. Anyway. .I guess i need to just accept this is the design.

Comment: Does this work when the code is deployed to a Function App? Then you don't have a local.settings.json.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to instantiate a new `ConfigurationBuilder`, you can simply format your settings in another way. Your `local.settings.json` file would look like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
    "Hello": "world",
    "ClientConfiguration__this": "that",
    "ClientConfiguration__SubscriberEndpoint": "........",
    "ClientConfiguration__Username": "........",
    .....
 }
}
```

Please note that the double underscores are important, as it instructs the environment variables reader to take `this` as a property of the complex object `ClientConfiguration`.
Your custom properties have to be located inside the `Values` object, otherwise they won't be injected as environment variables.

Comment: Just a heads up that the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file) explicitly states that setting names should not contain double underscores (`__`) or colons (`:`), so I wouldn't rely on this if it currently works.

Comment: @Damiene: The documentation says that the settings should not contain those chars because they are used by the runtime. That's exactly the purpose. Actually you should'nt used those chars if you don't want to see your setting treated as an object__property.
As a side note, this convention can also be used in the csproj properties, in the environment variables.

Comment: Adding a little bit more information. I create user-secrets which is a JSON where the name key uses ":". Those properties load into the configuration. So, following the same format, I was able to add the values I need. I could create a JSON object since the documentation says do not use arrays or objects.

Answer (score 0):

AS far as I know, Values collection is expected to be a Dictionary, if it contains any non-string values, it can cause Azure function can not read values from local.settings.json. For more details, please refer to the [blog](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/223#issuecomment-326225219)