# How to use Serilog configuration from azure app setting or a file for azure function app?

Tags: azure-functions, serilog

I am trying to add serilog to my azure function application. But I am not able to read serilog configuration from local.settings.json and I am not finding a way to get serilog configuration azure application setting.

**I like to read setting from configuration because my serilog settings are environment/platform specific.**

I have added below code in my startup.cs

```
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
               .CreateLogger();
```

in local.settings.jsonI have serilog config details.

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Seq",
        "Args": { "serverUrl": "http://DEV01:5341" }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logentries",
        "Args": { "Token": "ABCDXYZ" }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application settings in Azure portal or values in `local.settings.json` only accept `Dictionary<string, string>` format. If you use settings with more than one level in `local.settings.json`, it will ignore the whole "Values" section. It should be something like

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "key1":"value1"
  }
}
```

In Azure portal, also only key-value format.

[image]

You can get these settings in the environment variables in [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#environment-variables)

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("key")
```

So the workarounds are

1.you read and parse the json file.

2.use : to nest:keys:down

Reference:

[Azure Function Read local.settings.json to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843564/azure-function-read-local-settings-json-to-object)

[azure application settings - how to add nested item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55497468/azure-application-settings-how-to-add-nested-item)